# SQL Cast Error ODBC when moving from SQL client to excel

Tags: sql, excel, odbc, dbase

i am using the below Query to look at credit limit utilisation in the client it works perfectly but when transferring to excel as an ODBC connection I get the following error:

> ODBC: ERROR [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC dBASE Driver] Syntax error
> (missing operator) in query expression 'CAST(((ffdamdu / ffdcltm) *
> 100) AS DECIMAL(10, 2))'

Code as follows:

```
SELECT ffdarcd AS Account_Status,
       ffdcusn AS Customer_Number,
       ffdcnmb AS Customer_Name,
       rabcnbr AS Collector,
       ffdtrmc AS Customer_Terms,
       ffdcltm AS Current_Credit_Limit,
       ffdamdu AS Due,
       ffdage0 AS "CURRENT",
       ffdage1 AS Last_Period,
       ffdage2 AS "1 PERIOD OVERDUE",
       ffdage3 AS "2 PERIOD OVERDUE",
       ffdage4 AS "3 OR MORE PERIODS OVERDUE",
       CAST(((ffdamdu / ffdcltm) * 100) AS DECIMAL(10, 2)) AS Credit_Limit_Utilization
    FROM pwrdta.ffdcstbp b
         LEFT JOIN pwrdta.RABWTCLL0
             ON ffdcmpn = rabcmpn
                 AND ffddivn = rabdivn
                 AND ffddptn = rabdptn
                 AND ffdcusn = rabcusn
    WHERE ffdcmpn = '  1'
          AND ffddivn = '  1'
          AND ffddptn = '  1'
          AND ffdarcd <> 'D'
          AND ffdamdu <> 0
          AND ffdcltm <> 0
          AND FFDCHLD <> 'Y'
    ORDER BY Credit_Limit_Utilization DESC
```